# How to remove a captcha?

Tags: javascript, php

I have add CaptchMe on my website. 
Screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

The problem is that there can be only 1 CaptchMe on the same page. The sidebar is include on each page.

The solution in the remove the captcha in the sidebar when the sidebar is closed, and the capcha on the page is displayed. If the sidebar is open with a click, the captcha on the page need to be removed and the capcha on the sidebar displayed.

How can I do it ?

To display the captcha, I use

```html
<?php echo captchme_generate_html($publicKey, $error, $ssl, $customAttributes); ?>
```

If I add it in a div, I can remove the content with

```html
document.getElementById("captcha").innerHTML = "";
```

But after, when the sidebar is closed, I can't display it again because the div is empty. And I can't do

```html
document.getElementById("captcha").innerHTML = "<?php echo captchme_generate_html($publicKey, $error, $ssl, $customAttributes); ?> ";
```

Because this is impossible.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why don't you use something like recaptcha that can support multiple captchas on a page? https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Comment: Because Recaptcha don't give money :P

Comment: It's irrelevant to the question but... Adding a captcha to a sign-in form just to get some cents is so evil xD

Answer (score 0):

To regenerate the captacha you should be able to put the captcha PHP into it's own file on the server.
Then use JQuery .load() on the php file to make an AJAX call and load the response HTML directly into the DOM.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good idea.

The sidebar is removed with a javascript function. But how to run the ajax function with the javascript fonction ?

For exemple,

function closeSideBar() {
    Code to remove the sidebar
    Code to run the ajax function which add the php script in the div
}

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("span").click(function(){
        $("#captcha").load("captchme.php");
    });
});
 
function closeNav() {
 document.getElementById("captcha").innerHTML = ""; 
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "350px";
}

It run the ajax function when I click on a span, but how to run the ajax function when closeNav() is run ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very easy solution after 5 hours ...
I add the login form with an iframe in the sidebar and the other captcha (left) in directly on the page.

The main page is a page and the iframe an other page.

And I can add 2 CaptchMe on the same page :)

Thank you for the help, I learn one more element in jquery :)

Comment: That's more like a hack than a solution. Only barbarians use iframes for content that is within the same domain.